# Error validations failing in Rails 4 when using form_for

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, validation

I have a Rails app that builds both a User and an Organization when the first User signs up (User belongs_to Organization). This works fine, and if you fail to put in e.g. the email address (or use an incorrect one) then the form renders the relevant rails error messages just fine. I have additional logic that ensures the first User to sign up an Organization becomes the Admin User of that Organization, and they are permitted to add other users to the site too. If you try and sign up with an existing Organization name it's not permitted.

My tests are all fine, and I'm using the skeleton logic for authentication and authorization provided by the Hartl tutorial (not the new draft one). What I recently noticed was that when an Admin User inputs a blank form for a new user, the app returns to the Organization page and displays a success message. No User object is built (so some part of the app is still working) - I just don't want this to happen (I want the error messages displayed). I can't quite work out what is happening here - why wouldn't the "validates" statements return the errors in this case? Anyway - here's my code:

User.rb:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :organization
has_many :sales_opportunities
before_save { self.email = email.downcase }
before_destroy :allocate_sales_opportunities_to_admin
before_create :create_remember_token
validates :name, presence: true, length: { maximum: 50 }
VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-]+(?:\.[a-z\d\-]+)*\.[a-z]+\z/i
validates :email, presence: true, format: { with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX }, uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }
has_secure_password
validates :password, length: { minimum: 6 }
validates :organization, presence: true
```

Organization.rb:

```
class Organization < ActiveRecord::Base
validates :organization_name, presence: true, length: { maximum: 50 }, uniqueness: true 
has_many :users, :inverse_of => :organization, dependent: :destroy
has_many :companies, :inverse_of => :organization, dependent: :destroy
has_many :products, :inverse_of => :organization, dependent: :destroy
has_many :competitors, :inverse_of => :organization, dependent: :destroy
accepts_nested_attributes_for :users
after_create :set_admin

def users_for_form
  collection = users.where(organization_id: id)

  collection.any? ? collection : users.build
end

 private   
  def set_admin
     if   self.users.count == 1
       self.users.first.update_attribute(:admin, true)
   else
   return true
  end
  end

end
```

Users controller:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  before_action :signed_in_user, only: [:index, :edit, :update]
  before_action :correct_user,   only: [:edit, :update, :show]
  before_action :admin_user,    only: :destroy  
def update
if @user.update_attributes(user_params)
  flash[:success] = "Profile updated"
  redirect_to @user
else
  render 'edit'
end
end

 def create 
   if signed_in?
    @organization = Organization.find(params[:organization_id])
   @organization.users.create(user_params)
    flash[:success] = "You added a new user to your organization. Send them their login details today!"
    redirect_to @organization
   else
     @user = User.new(user_params)
    if @user.save
      sign_in @user
    flash[:success] = "Thanks for signing up with My App! This is your profile page, be sure to take a look at the support link in the footer"
    redirect_to @user
else
    render 'new'
  end
  end
 end

private
def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, organization_attributes: [:organization_name, :organization_id])

end

#before filters

def signed_in_user
 unless signed_in?
   store_location
  redirect_to signin_url, notice: "Please sign in." unless signed_in?
  end
end

def admin_user
  redirect_to(root_url) unless current_user.admin?
 end

def correct_user
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
  @organization = @user.organization
  redirect_to root_url, notice: "You are not permitted to visit that page. Please create an account or sign in" unless current_user?(@user) || @user.organization ==     current_user.organization
end

end
```

Organization's controller:

```
 class OrganizationsController < ApplicationController
 before_action :signed_in_user, only: [:edit, :update, :show]
 before_action :correct_org,   only: [:edit, :update, :show]

  def new
    @organization = Organization.new
    @organization.users.build
  end    
def create
   @organization = Organization.new(organization_params)
   if @organization.save
     @user = @organization.users.first
    sign_in @user
     flash[:success] = "Thanks for signing up with My App! This is your profile page, be sure to take a look at the support link in the footer"
  redirect_to @user
 else
  render 'new'
end
end
```

I'm sure I've got some ugly code in here (the Organizations and Users features were the first new functionality I built when learning RoR and deviating from the Hartl course), and I can't quite work out why the validations are working (no User object is created) when the error message handling is not. For completeness here's the add user form:

```
<% provide(:title, 'Add more users to your organization') %>
<div class-"container-fluid">
    <h1>Sign up colleagues using the form below:</h1>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
        <div class="well">
            <%= form_for([:organization, @user], :html => {:class => "form-horizontal"}) do |f| %>
                <%= render 'shared/error_messages' %>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <%= f.label :name, :class => "col-md-4 control-label" %>
                    <div class ="col-md-8">
                        <%= f.text_field :name, :placeholder => "What's their name?" %>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <%= f.label :email, :class => "col-md-4 control-label" %>
                    <div class ="col-md-8">
                        <%= f.text_field :email, :placeholder => "Enter their email address" %>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <%= f.label :password, :class => "col-md-4 control-label" %>
                    <div class ="col-md-8">
                        <%= f.password_field :password, :placeholder => "Provide a password" %>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <%= f.label :password_confirmation, "Repeat Password", :class => "col-md-4 control-label" %>
                    <div class ="col-md-8">
                        <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation, :placeholder => "Repeat password" %>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <%= f.submit "Add new user account", class: "btn btn-large btn-success" %>
            <% end %>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here's the working form for a new Organization/User combo:

```
<% provide(:title, 'Sign up') %>
<div class="container-fluid">
<h1>Sign up!</h1>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
    </div>
</div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
            <div class="well">
                    <%= form_for(@organization, :html => {:class => "form-horizontal"}) do |f| %> 
                        <%= render 'shared/org_error_messages' %>
                         <div class="form-group">
                            <%= f.label :organization_name, :class => "col-md-4 control-label" %>
                            <div class ="col-md-8">
                            <%= f.text_field :organization_name, :placeholder => "Who do you work for?" %>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                            <%= f.fields_for :users, @organization.users_for_form do |user| %>
                             <div class="form-group"> 
                                <%= user.label :name, :class => "col-md-4 control-label" %>
                                <div class ="col-md-8">
                                <%= user.text_field :name, :placeholder => "What's your name?" %>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                             <div class="form-group">
                                <%= user.label :email, :class => "col-md-4 control-label" %>
                                <div class ="col-md-8">
                                <%= user.text_field :email, :placeholder => "Email" %>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                             <div class="form-group">
                                <%= user.label :password, :class => "col-md-4 control-label" %>
                                <div class ="col-md-8">
                                <%= user.password_field :password, :placeholder => "Enter password - minimum 6 characters" %>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                             <div class="form-group">
                                <%= user.label :password_confirmation, "Repeat Password", :class => "col-md-4 control-label" %>
                                <div class ="col-md-8">
                                <%= user.password_field :password_confirmation, :placeholder => "Repeat password" %>
                                </div>
                        </div>

                            <%= user.hidden_field :organization_id, input_html: {value: @organization.id} %>
                        <% end %>
                        <%= f.submit "Create my account", class: "btn btn-large btn-success" %>
                        <% end %>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
<div>
```

Where am I going wrong?

EDIT - here is the log from my console when the above happens:

```
   Processing by UsersController#new as HTML
  Parameters: {"organization_id"=>"1"}
  Rendered shared/_error_messages.html.erb (0.1ms)
  Rendered users/new.html.erb within layouts/application (3.4ms)
  Rendered layouts/_shim.html.erb (0.0ms)
  User Load (0.6ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"  WHERE "users"."remember_token" = 'b8cabbe1e1514f14be24f95d48248ad716e11342' LIMIT 1
  Organization Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "organizations".* FROM "organizations"  WHERE "organizations"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
  Rendered layouts/_header.html.erb (3.9ms)
  Rendered layouts/_footer.html.erb (0.2ms)
Completed 200 OK in 28ms (Views: 26.0ms | ActiveRecord: 0.9ms)


Started POST "/organizations/1/users" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-10-05 22:22:15 +0630
Processing by UsersController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"fKx7bdWtC7bmBKMRF3ivwBlmJXzrcWJ16dYYOfNLBC0=", "user"=>{"name"=>"", "email"=>"", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]"}, "commit"=>"Add new user account", "organization_id"=>"1"}
  User Load (0.6ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"  WHERE "users"."remember_token" = 'b8cabbe1e1514f14be24f95d48248ad716e11342' LIMIT 1
  Organization Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "organizations".* FROM "organizations"  WHERE "organizations"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
   (0.3ms)  BEGIN
  User Exists (0.5ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "users"  WHERE LOWER("users"."email") = LOWER('') LIMIT 1
   (0.8ms)  COMMIT
    Redirected to http://0.0.0.0:3000/organizations/1
    Completed 302 Found in 14ms (ActiveRecord: 2.7ms)


Started GET "/organizations/1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-10-05 22:22:15 +0630
Processing by OrganizationsController#show as HTML
  Parameters: {"id"=>"1"}
  User Load (0.6ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"  WHERE "users"."remember_token" = 'b8cabbe1e1514f14be24f95d48248ad716e11342' LIMIT 1
  Organization Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "organizations".* FROM "organizations"  WHERE "organizations"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT  "organizations".* FROM "organizations"  WHERE "organizations"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", "1"]]
  User Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users"  WHERE "users"."organization_id" = $1  [["organization_id", 1]]
  Rendered organizations/_users_index.html.erb (1.0ms)
  Organization Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "organizations".* FROM "organizations"  WHERE "organizations"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
  Company Load (0.6ms)  SELECT "companies".* FROM "companies"  WHERE "companies"."organization_id" = $1  [["organization_id", 1]]
  Competitor Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "competitors".* FROM "competitors"  WHERE "competitors"."organization_id" = $1  [["organization_id", 1]]
  Product Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "products".* FROM "products"  WHERE "products"."organization_id" = $1  [["organization_id", 1]]
  Rendered organizations/show.html.erb within layouts/application (13.3ms)
  Rendered layouts/_shim.html.erb (0.0ms)
  Rendered layouts/_header.html.erb (0.6ms)
  Rendered layouts/_footer.html.erb (0.2ms)
Completed 200 OK in 37ms (Views: 30.6ms | ActiveRecord: 3.1ms)
```

Comment: Can you post content of log file when admin user inputs a blank form for a new user? Also, In `UsersController` use `@organization.users.create!(user_params)` and see if it throws any error.

Comment: @Nitish - I've just added the log file. I'll try the UsersController change now and update here.

Comment: If I use @organization.users.create!(user_params) it takes me to an Action Controller error with the error messages listed: ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid in UsersController#create
Validation failed: Name can't be blank, Email can't be blank, Email is invalid, Password can't be blank, Password is too short (minimum is 6 characters)

Comment: And just to be clear - I've gone and found Organization with the id=1, and listed all Users in the console - there are only the two valid users that are listed (not the ones that are apparently created during this process).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this with the change to the create function in the Users controller - I was creating a new @organization.user regardless of the error messages in the form. Instead I needed to use @user = @organization.users.new, and then use the same if @user.save ... test that works for a new user. See the below code for how it was fixed:

```
  def create 
if signed_in?
  @organization = Organization.find(params[:organization_id])
  @user = @organization.users.new(user_params)
  if @user.save
    flash[:success] = "You added a new user to your organization. Send them their login details today!"
    redirect_to @organization
  else
    render 'new'
  end
else
@user = User.new(user_params)
if @user.save
  sign_in @user
    flash[:success] = "Thanks for signing up with My App! This is your profile page, be sure to take a look at the support link in the footer"
    redirect_to @user
else
    render 'new'
  end
 end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it's something to do with the way I'm handling creating a new user, after further testing. The following code is almost certainly where the error lies:

```
 def create 
  if signed_in?
@organization = Organization.find(params[:organization_id])
@organization.users.create(user_params)
flash[:success] = "You added a new user to your organization. Send them their login details today!"
 redirect_to @organization
else
 @user = User.new(user_params)
if @user.save
  sign_in @user
flash[:success] = "Thanks for signing up with My App! This is your profile page, be sure to take a look at the support link in the footer"
redirect_to @user
   else
    render 'new'
   end
 end
end
```

Where I'm testing if the User is signed in, the choice either leads to adding a new user to the current organization or creating both from scratch. What I need is a way to test whether @organization.users.create was successful (or maybe I need @organization.users.new) and if it fails the validations then I need to render "users/new" rather than heading back to the @organization path and displaying the (obviously incorrect) flash that a new user has been created.

Anyone got any ideas how I test for this? I tried a quick if/else test (along the lines of "if @organization.users.create ... else: render the users/new page"), but then I got a bunch of form errors because I wasn't defining the object that the page was creating.